# Skip Exception and keep adding the rows in db

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

I am writing a java routine to add rows in a table. I have used try catch clause. 
When there is a duplicate entry the code throws -803 exception and terminates the program.

What I need is the program to skip the duplicate entry and add the new ones.

Code :

```
            try{

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db2url); 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcurl,user,password);
            Statement statehits = conn.createStatement();
            Statement state = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet srt = state.executeQuery("select * from dbo.v_IDM");
            while(srt.next())
            {
                statehits.executeUpdate("insert into maximo.hits (HITSID,HASLD,EMPLOYEEID,LOGON_NAME,DESIGNATION,DEPARTMENT,MANAGERNUMBER,MANAGERNAME,LOCATION) values ("+srt.getString("EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")+", 0 ,'"+ srt.getString("EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")+"','"+ srt.getString("LOGON_NAME")+"','"+ srt.getString("DESIGNATION")+"','"+srt.getString("DEPARTMENT")+"','"+ srt.getString("MANAGERNUMBER")+"','"+ srt.getString("MANAGERNAME")+"','"+ srt.getString("LOCATION")+"')");
                count++;
            }
            System.out.print(count);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: and ... what exactly is stopping you with that?

Comment: Just add try and cacth clause under while cicle. In this way the while cicle don't end.

Comment: You really should not concatenate values into a query string like this. It makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection (eg consider what happens `MANAGERNAME` is `O'Reilly`). Use a prepared statement. To your actual problem, surround the the loop body with try-catch...

Comment: You cannot recover from an exception. You need to check for duplicates beforehand. See more -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282351